# Black marble Node material

Tags: shaders

Hi I'd like to create a marble chessboard with white and black squares.

For the white Rectangles I use the material shown in the picture.

What I want to create now is a identical material for black pieces - probably just inverted somehow - I played around with the invert node - didn't work...

How to create a black marble material white white wave lines?

[image: Material node for white marble material]

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this - color ramp was the solution[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You are supposed to take fac output from the noise texture node and plug it in base color on principled BSDF
2. To inver the color, add a math node, set the first value to 1 and connect the second value (the bottom one) to the Fac from noise texture node

Comment: Which "Function" would I set in the Math node?  It defaults to Add

Comment: subtract, sorry

Comment: thanks for the reply - had issues to follow exactly what you explained (where to connect the Noise node on the left? and: which Math node, Add, Divide, etc...?)

Answer (score 0):

I always try to cheat ;)

I used the included [Materials Library](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/addons/materials/material_library.html) that has a "marble tiles" material (white), unpacked the image and used GIMP image editor to invert and darken to near black marble.

Here is the packed blend file with the "marble_tiles_black.jpg" included:  [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I had this in mind but it is a bit against my principle as I made the white without texture...